# Hosting C# Telegram Bot

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

I wrote a Telegram bot in C# in a simple Console Application project. The bot works great when it runs on my computer, but I can not run it on my computer forever... Is it possible to upload a Console Application to a free server so that it will always run? If so, I would be happy to receive a recommendation for sites that offer this option. Thanks in advance.
(Sorry about my English, this is not my native language ..)

Comment: Asking for off-site resources if off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new here. I'll know next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host it as an Azure WebJob, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs, or Azure Function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference. I think this contains all the information you need to get what you want!

Comment: @DourHighArch is right, this site is not for people who are looking for a link. Try to google more next time, so you don't need to ask these questions here :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new here. I'll know next.

Comment: No problem, just speaking out of experience